# How to get the best model when using EarlyStopping callback in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am training a neural network with Keras using `EarlyStopping` based on `val_acc` and `patience=0`. `EarlyStopping` stops the training as soon as `val_acc` decreases.

However the final model that I obtain is not the best model, namely the one with the highest `val_acc`. But I rather have the model corresponding to the epoch after, namely the one corresponding to a `val_acc` just a bit lower than the best one and that caused the early stopping!

How do I get the best one?

I tried to use the save the best model using the callback:

```
ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
```

But I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to save the highest accuracy then you should set the checkpoint `monitor='val_acc'` it will automatically save on highest. Lowest loss might not necessarily correspond to highest accuracy. You can also set `verbose=1` to see which model is being saved and why.

Comment: I actually do that. I monitor on val_acc. I am now setting verbose to 1 to se what happens

Comment: This answer s correct. Your training will go on for 1 epoch even if you set `patiente` to 0. Simply because logically you need one more epoch to identify that the model is no longer improving. Nevertheless `ModelCheckpoint` saves the best model for you. You just need to load it: `best_model = load_model(filepath='best_model.h5')`

Answer (score 16):

In [Keras 2.2.3](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.3), a new argument called `restore_best_weights` have been introduced for [`EarlyStopping`](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/) callback that if set to `True` (defaults to `False`), it would restore the weights from the epoch with the best monitored quantity:

> **restore_best_weights:** whether to restore model weights from the epoch with the best value of the monitored quantity. If `False`, the
> model weights obtained at the last step of training are used.