# Early Stopping, Model has gone through how many epochs?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am using Keras. I am training my Neural Network and using Early Stopping. My patience is 10 and the epoch with the lowest validation loss is 15. My network runs til 25 epochs and stops however my model is the one with 25 epochs not 15 if I understand correctly

Is there an easy way to revert to the 15 epoch model or do I need to re-instantiate the model and run 15 epochs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the best model when using EarlyStopping callback in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432476/how-to-get-the-best-model-when-using-earlystopping-callback-in-keras)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is one, the `restore_best_weights` parameter in the `EarlyStopping` callback, set this to True and Keras will keep track of the weights producing the best loss:

```
callback = EarlyStopping(..., restore_best_weights=True)
```

See all the parameters for this callback [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you get the model (weights) corresponding to the epoch when it stops. A commonly used strategy is to save the model whenever the validation loss/acc improves.

Comment: Actually, you can restore the best model using `EarlyStopping` callback. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52613051/2099607).

Answer (score 0):

Early Stopping doesn't work the way you are thinking, that it should return the lowest loss or highest accuracy model, it works if there is no improvement in model accuracy or loss, for about x epochs (10 in your case, the patience parameter) then it will stop. 
you should use callback modelcheckpoint functions instead e.g.

`keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)`

https://keras.io/callbacks/

This will save or checkpoint best model encountered during the training history.

Comment: Actually, you can restore the best model using `EarlyStopping` callback. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52613051/2099607).

Comment: Thanks for updating me as well, i wasnt aware of new update in keras.