# When training neural networks, does Tensorflow automatically revert back to the best epoch after finishing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, epoch

If not, why not? Sometimes I will have an epoch that gets 95ish % and then finish with an epoch that has 10% or so less accuracy. I just never can tell whether it reverts back to that best epoch.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to save your model file on disk by using `ModelCheckpoint` callback. Instead, you can use `EarlyStopping` callback to get the best model. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52613051/2099607).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using Keras,then in ModelCheckpoint callback, set save_best_only=True. If this option is enabled, then it saves the model which shows the best results based on the metric you set, either loss or accuracy which you mention for ***monitor*** attribute.

Read more about it here - https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint

Comment: Thanks. I tried the earlystopping callback for some reason. This looks like a better match

Comment: if you find this answer useful, please mark this as accepted answer which will be helpful for future users. thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)